# Render multiple outputs to PDF from RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have **a function** that will create 2 dataframes and a plot. I want to display them all. I tried using option `results = 'asis'` but the problem is it only render the plot and no dataframes. If I wrap those dataframes inside a `print` then it only render the dataframes and not the plot.

The code looks like this:

`kable(df1)
...
kable(df2)
...
plotResult() {
 ...
 ggplot()... # Plot the result
 ...
}`

How can I print these multiple tables in the kable nice format and also render the plot? I tried searching on SO and elsewhere but in vain. I want to have everything inside a function, meaning that the users can input the numbers and it will pop out the dataframes and plot.

Comment: Separate chunks?

Comment: Everything is inside a function so I can't separate them. I edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Okay, capture the output such as `out <- myfunc(...)`; then in three separate chunks all out each component. Or does your function operate solely in side-effect? Often not a great idea, for reasons such as this.

Comment: Yes I did exactly what you said, as a work-around. I'm still curious why we can't just have the function output everything. I thought ` results = 'asis' ` could help but seems like it's only for the output format.

Comment: The two `kable` calls should work because they're just printing straight text. However, the way that `knitr` captures the plot is a little differently, since it has to determine at compile-time the dimensions of the plot. You might be able to workaround this by manually saving with `ggsave` or such, then output the latex commands to bring in an image. (The point is that referencing code-generated tables is one thing, but code-generated images are a different beast.)

Comment: In my experience, when I have a situation similar to what you're talking about here, I have found it much better (in literally every case I've had) to break that into three separate function calls. One reason is for precisely this reason.